# Scala can't access Java inner class?

Tags: java, scala, inner-classes

I have a java class that looks like this:

```
public class Constants {
    public class Commands {
        public static final String CreateOrder = "CreateOrder";
    }
}
```

I want to access "CreateOrder" constant, In java I can access it easily like this:

```
String co = Constants.Commands.CreateOrder
```

But in Scala this doesn't work why???
How can I access "CreateOrder" from Scala, I can't alter the Java code.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try `Constants$Command$CreateOrder` ?

Comment: Constants$Command$CreateOrder didn't work

Comment: Why is `Commands` non-static?

Comment: I'm using an other java banking lib and i didn't write the java code and cant change it.

Comment: This incompatibility is bugging me now. Has anyone found an alternative approach other than reflection?

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, there is no way to do what you want in Scala.

But if you absolutely cannot change the Java code then you could resort to some reflection trickery.

```
val value = classOf[Constants#Commands].getDeclaredField("CreateOrder").get(null)
```

Comment: I spent hours searching for a solution to this problem.  I'm using a 3rd party lib that has constants defined this way.  This was the only thing that worked.  The suggestion below by @Travis Brown to instantiate an object then access it did not work for me.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.

In the case of constant variables, you can use the `Constants.Commands.CreateOrder` syntax even though normally any reference to `Constants.Commands` would have to be associated with an instance of `Constants`, since it's not a static inner class.

This could be considered something of a crazy one-off syntactic special case in Java, and it's the kind of thing that the Scala language designers haven't bothered to bake into Scala's Java interoperability.

Your best bet (if your real Java class looks exactly like this) is to create an instance of `Constants`, at which point you can access the inner class's static field in a perfectly natural way:

```
scala> (new Constants).Commands.CreateOrder
res0: String = CreateOrder
```

If for some reason this isn't an option you'll have to go with the reflection-based approach in the other answer, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

I think a third alternative to reflection and instantiation is to write a small piece of Java glue code. Like

```
public class Glue {
    public static String createOrder() { return Constants.Commands.CreateOrder; }
}
```

Then from Scala you should be able to write `Glue.createOrder`.

Comment: That's a good alternative to my reflection based answer. If you are able/allowed to add new Java code to an application, this is a superior option.

Comment: As a side note: When building with sbt, throwing a .java file into the mix works out of the box. It is often a quick work around the corner cases where Java and Scala perspectives don't match (I think visibility is another case)