# value Engine is not a member of object android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech

Tags: java, android, eclipse, scala, text-to-speech

In java, using android-19, this works fine:

```
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.Engine;
```

But in scala:

```
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.Engine
                                       ^
error: value Engine is not a member of object android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech
```

This is weird because I can import `EngineInfo` without problems, but it does not recognize the class `Engine`, although it is clearly in the android.jar

Any fix or workaround? Is this a scala issue? I'm developping on Eclipse 3.7 using AndroidProguardScala v51 and Scala IDE version 3.0.1

**EDIT**

The context in which I am using this is for example the following:

```
if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
  mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, mTtsListener)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `TextToSpeech.Engine` is declared non-static which means something like this:

```
public class TextToSpeech {
    public class Engine {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345798/scala-cant-access-java-inner-class), you can't access it. Here's my workaround using a wrapper:

```
object ConstantsWrapper {
  private val cls = classOf[TextToSpeech#Engine]
  def apply(fieldName: String) = cls.getDeclaredField(fieldName).get(null)
                                    .toString

  val CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS = apply("CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS")
  // Insert more here
}

if (resultCode == ConstantsWrapper.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
  mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, mTtsListener)
}
```