# Why are nested Java classes not importable from Scala?

Tags: scala

How am I supposed to mock a nested Java class using **scalamock**, especially when said nested Java class is coming from a third party library?

Given the following sources:

**src/main/java/Outer.java**

```
/**
  * Outer class that offers a Nested class inaccessible from Scala :(
  */
 public class Outer {
   public class Nested {

   }
 }
```

**src/main/java/UseNestedJavaClassFromJava.java**

```
public class UseNestedJavaClassFromJava {
   private Outer.Nested nested;
 }
```

**src/main/scala/ImportNestedJavaClass.scala**

```
// TODO uncomment the below line to break the build
//import Outer.Nested
```

Uncommenting the scala import line results in a compilation failure while compiling *UseNestedJavaClassFromJava.java* works just fine.

Full minimal example with gradle: https://github.com/billyjf/async-http-client-gradle-scala.

Apparently this was somewhat already addressed in the below question, but resorting to Java glue code or reflection trickery just for the sake of testing Scala code that leverages a Java library with nested Java classes seems a bit unreasonable to me, is there really no other solution?

[Scala can't access Java inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345798/scala-cant-access-java-inner-class)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ✅

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Main { 
  val z = new Outer; 
  private[this] val y:z.Inner = null 
}
```

For more context:

1. Outer.Inner is interpreted as Outer$.Inner (companion object).
2. Official Scala website:

> As opposed to Java-like languages where such inner classes are members
>   of the enclosing class, in Scala such inner classes are bound to the
>   outer object.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/inner-classes.html

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I can say two things - one is that Outer.Inner is interpreted as Outer$.Inner (companion object).
Other thing is this line
`As opposed to Java-like languages where such inner classes are members of the enclosing class, in Scala such inner classes are bound to the outer object.`
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/inner-classes.html

Comment: Great, you an edit your answer you know?  It's always better now to have to read the comments to get the full picture.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a solution using Mockito:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class OuterNestedTest extends FlatSpec with MockFactory with Matchers with MockitoSugar {
  "Nested Java class" should "be mockable using Mockito from within a scalatest" in {
    val mockedNestedJavaClass = Mockito.mock(classOf[Outer#Nested])

    Mockito.when(mockedNestedJavaClass.methodWithAParam("some value"))
      .thenReturn("mocked", Nil: _*)

    mockedNestedJavaClass.methodWithAParam("some value") shouldBe "mocked"
  }
}
```